# Error Permission Denied When start grunt in Openshift

Tags: node.js, npm

I Have got error when trying to deploy my app in openshift , anyone have an idea?

I'm using the following environment config:

```
DEV_MODE=false
NODE_ENV=production
DEBUG_PORT=5858
```

This is the error log:

```
Launching via npm...
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@2.14.13
npm info using node@v0.10.40
npm info prestart xsis-atrium@0.0.1
npm info start xsis-atrium@0.0.1
> xsis-atrium@0.0.1 start /opt/app-root/src
> grunt
***sh: /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/.bin/grunt: Permission denied***
npm info xsis-atrium@0.0.1 Failed to exec start script
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin/npm" "run" "-d" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.13
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! xsis-atrium@0.0.1 start: `grunt`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the xsis-atrium@0.0.1 start script 'grunt'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the xsis-atrium package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     grunt
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls xsis-atrium
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /opt/app-root/src/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: I have the same. No idea what is causing this...